# Add a column to a CSV that is scraped by python selenium

Tags: python, csv, selenium, web-scraping

Below is python code that extracts a CSV file from a website using selenium. When you originally go to this website (Fangraphs.com), you can export data from an "export data" link that packages the desired data in a CSV. The code essentially opens up Firefox and executes the "Export Data" button to download the CSV to a folder on my computer. Does anyone know if it is possible to insert an additional column of data to the scraped CSV? The additional column would only contain one value. For example, a column that lists the year (2018). I was thinking the Pandas package might be useful in this case, but I wasn't sure how it would interact with the selenium scraper. Thanks in advance for the advice!

```
import sys
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile


today = datetime.today()
download_dir = os.getcwd()
default_filepath = os.path.join(download_dir, 'Fangraphs Leaderboard.csv')
desired_filepath = os.path.join(download_dir, 
'{}_{}_{}_steamer.csv'.format(today.year, today.month, today.day))
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 'text/csv')
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://www.fangraphs.com/projections.aspx? 
pos=all&stats=bat&type=steamer")
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Export Data').click()

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()

if os.path.isfile(default_filepath):
  os.rename(default_filepath, desired_filepath)
  print('Renamed file {} to {}'.format(default_filepath, desired_filepath))
else:
  sys.exit('Error, unable to locate file at {}'.format(default_filepath))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas indeed is the best choice:

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_csv_file_path.csv")
df["year"] = 2018
df.to_csv("your_new_csv_file_path.csv")
```